# Ember Trigger Controller Action from Template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, templates, ember.js, controller, handlebars.js

I'll explain what I want to do first, as maybe there's a better solution than what I'm trying: I'm using a bootstrap grid layout and trying to create new rows and columns programmatically depending on my model using ember. What I have now is:

```
{{#each model}}
    {{#if beginRow}}
            <div class="row">
    {{/if}}
    <div class="col-sm-3">
            stuff
    </div>
    {{#if endRow}}
            </div>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

I made `beginRow` and `endRow` computed properties based on a counter that I want to increment every time I loop through the each.

```
App.MyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    currentIndex: 0,
    beginRow: function() {
        if(this.get('currentIndex')%3 == 0) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }.property('currentIndex'),
    endRow: function() {
        if(this.get('currentIndex')%3 == 0) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }.property('currentIndex'),
    actions: {
        incrementCurrentIndex: function() {
            this.incrementProperty('currentIndex');
        },
    }
});
```

I think this would work, but the missing piece here is calling the `incrementCurrentIndex` method every loop. Is that possible? A thought that just occurred to me is to use a custom handlebars helper to increment the property, but I'm not sure it would have access to the controller. Is there a better alternative to what I'm trying to do that I'm overlooking? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great solution! Rather than using my controller, I get the index I'm at in the each helper using `_view.contentIndex`, and send that value to two Handlebars Helpers as follows:

```
{{#each model}}
    {{isNewRow _view.contentIndex 3}}
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        stuff   
    </div>
    {{isEndOfRow _view.contentIndex 3}}
{{/each}}
```

And the helpers calculate if this should be a new row or not based off of the index and number of columns:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('isNewRow', function(index, columns) {
    if(index%columns == 0)
        return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('<div class="row">');
});

Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('isEndOfRow', function(index, columns) {
    if(index%columns == columns-1)
        return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('</div>');
});
```

Hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend dividing your array into small arrays which has 3 elements in it.
Handlebars is not good place for writing logic. Always try to move your logic into your controller.

In your template

```
{{#each slice in slicedArray}}
  <div class="row">
    {{#each item in slice}}
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        {{!-- Do your stuff --}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

For your controller

```
App.MyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  slicedArray: function(){
    // slice your array into small ones and return it
  }.property('model');
});
```